# How to get data from form to javascript and redirect to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, local-storage

I have a html5 form with name, surname ect. The reason why I'm using  a form is so that the user has to fill in everything, for that I'm using `required`. I want to save all the data in localStorage, for that I need to move the data to JavaScript.

How do access the data in JavaScript when the `submit` button is pressed while redirecting the user to another page?

This is the code:

***Html5***

```
<form id="TheForm" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="*Förnamn" required >
   <input type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="*Efternamn" required >
   <input type="email" id="FirstEmail" placeholder="*e-postadress" autocomplete="on" required >
   <input type="email" id="SecondEmail" placeholder="*Verifiera e-postadress" autocomplete="off" required >
   <input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="*Adress" required >
   <input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="function()" value="Skicka">
</form>
```

Comment: Is jQuery an option? If so, serialize the form data and then store it.

Comment: could work i guess.. any other way though?

Comment: actually, no it won't work

Comment: With Vanilla JS, you can access DOM elements directly. For example, `var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;` will store the value of Name in a JS variable called "name".

Comment: will this only be called when all the fields a filled? should i put the function in onclick="" for the button and the next page in action in the form tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var submit = function () {
    window.localStorage.name = document.getElementById('Name').value;

    // Save all the other fields
    // You either return a non-false value here and let the form submit
    // Or you return false and do a window.location change 
};

window.onload = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById('TheForm');

    if (form.attachEvent) {
        form.attachEvent('submit', submit);
    } else {
        form.addEventListener('submit', submit);
    }
}
```

Comment: should i give the functions names?

Comment: haha by that response, i guess not :D i meant the var submit = functon () and windows.onload = function()

Comment: btw, console giving an error: Cannot read property 'attachEvent' of null. Its showing the form.attachEvent line

Comment: What is the ID of your form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Java Script**

```
function storeDetails() {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
       localStorage.setItem('name', document.getElementById('Name').value));                              
       //code to store other values will go here
    } else {
        alert('Your browser do not support local storage');
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="TheForm" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:storeDetails();" action=" ">
   <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="*Förnamn" required >
   <input type="text" id="Surname" placeholder="*Efternamn" required >
   <input type="email" id="FirstEmail" placeholder="*e-postadress" autocomplete="on" required >
   <input type="email" id="SecondEmail" placeholder="*Verifiera e-postadress" autocomplete="off" required >
   <input type="text" id="Address" placeholder="*Adress" required >
   <input type="submit" id="Submit" onclick="function()" value="Skicka">
</form>
```