# How do I make an HTML-button both redirect the user to a new .html-page whilst also saving data from form input using .value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a form where a user gets to type in data that is saved in variables when the data is submitted. I am requesting a solution that will both save the user's data whilst also redirecting the user to a new .html-page when the button is pressed.

```
<button type="button" onclick="getInfo()">Submit</button>
```

As you can see above, the button is activating a function, that will save the info like this:

```
function getInfo(){
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value
    var adress = document.getElementById("adress").value
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value
}
```

How can I make this possible? Sincerely, Decentralized.

Comment: Save the data where?

Comment: You mean save those variables and use them in another HTML page? That can't be done, since on the new page those variables will not exist, or won't have the value you need, if not using server-side programming I think you can only use GET variables and get them through JS in the other page, besides localstorage.

Comment: The data is saved in the variables when the button is pressed, atleast I believe so. Example given: When the user types in her/his first name it will be stored in the variable "firstname".

Comment: @Decentralized they are only saved during your script's execution, after it's done they no longer have any data, nor exist for that matter.

Comment: tke a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20313203/how-to-get-data-from-form-to-javascript-and-redirect-to-another-page?rq=1

Comment: Did it help solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are searching for something like that :

```
function getInfo(){
    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value
    var adress = document.getElementById("adress").value
    var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value
    localStorage['firstname'] = firstname; // store data into browser's storage
    window.location = 'http://overpage.html'; // change the browser's page

}
```

Note :

you can access data one the ther page using

```
var firstnameNewPage = localStorage['firstname'];
```

take a look at `sessionStorage` if you want to keep data available only for session usage

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use form action with multiform attribute just like this

```
<form id="form_name" action="yourhtmlname.html" method="post" class="pure-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is not how you should handle credentias and authentication, but for the sake of this question, I'll ignore that.

Since your question is very broad and can have many possible answers.
So my answer is going to be general

**Here are some of the ways you can store this data and display it in another page are:**

1. Send the data to a server, so it can be stored in the server's session or database to be retrieved latter (via an ajax call, or html forms).
2. Make your app a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) so all your 'pages' share a state that can be used to move data around.

   Some examples of javascript frameworks from Wikipedia that are implemented as SPA:

   > AngularJS, Ember.js, Meteor.js, ExtJS and React
3. Use a browser APIs called **`sessionStorage` or `localStorage`**.
   They can be used to store key-value pairs of strings to be accessed latter for.
   You could also store JSON data in them using the `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` functions.

   ---

**My suggestion:**

From these possibilities I would say **option 3 (`localStorage`)** would be the easiest to implement with something like:

```
  localStorage.setItem('first name', fname);
```

and

```
  var fname = localStorage.getItem('first name');
```

Which would save these values in the browser.

And you can do `location.replace('/path/to/other/page.html')` right after that and load these values in the other page as long as you use it in the same domain.

Comment: If I would go with option 2, how would I actually go about in implementing this? The line of code you wrote, is that for option two? It being a single page application, does that make it impossible to reload to a new page? What lines of codes do I need to do this? What is the line of code to make the button both save the data (which I'm guessing is already done by me?) and also redirecting the user to a new page?

Comment: 1) I edited the answer to clarify. 2) The lines of code I showed were about option 3 (`localStorage` API). To implement a SPA it's really a different scope, and It's probably too much to edit the question/answer. I suggest you choose a javascript framework for that and google stuff, and only if you stumble into issues open a new question. 3) Your existing code doesn't help a lot, because you only saved the data into javascript variables (in RAM/memory), when you refresh the page all the data gets deleted. You need to save the data into a persistent kind of memory.

Comment: Ok, I think the best option is to learn a JavaScript framework. Which one would you recommend for a beginner?

Comment: I have experience only with `Angular`, and I don't think It's a beginner friendly framework. From what I saw by now `React` and `Vue.js` seems the easiest for beginners. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)